# How do I scrape data inside of the each product- which are individual subpages? [Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to scrape data from this website

```
url = "https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment?location=portugal&paged={page}"
```

After dealing with pagination, I wanted the scraper to also gather data inside of each individual 'product'. 'Features' are what I named the list I wanted to describe each product. I encountered a problem with iterating through each container while retaining the data inside -the 'Features'. Are there any alternative solutions? If not, can I have suggestions on how to approach the problem?

```html
locations = []
prices = []
links = []
spans = []

for page in range(1, 3):

    driver.get(url.format(page=page))
    containers = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="list"]')
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(1)

    # Headless mode
    # option = Options()
    # option.headless = True

    for container in containers:
        location = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./a/h3[@itemprop="name"]/span[@class="location"]').text
        price = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./a/h3[@itemprop="name"]/span[@class="price"]').text
        link = container.find_element(by="xpath", value='./a').get_attribute("href")
        locations.append(location)
        prices.append(price)
        links.append(link)

        misc_location = container.find_element(by ="xpath", value='./a')
        misc_location.click()

        features = driver.find_elements(by="xpath", value='//div[@class="feature-list"]/div/div')

        for feature in features:

            span = feature.find_element(by="xpath", value='./div/span/text()').text
            spans.append(span)

driver.quit()

my_dict = {'location': locations, 'price': prices, 'links': links, 'spans': spans}

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

To scrape the *Location*, *Price* and *Link* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment?location=portugal&paged=1'})
  locations = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list']/a//h3/span//span")))]
  prices = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list']/a//h3//span[@class='price']")))]
  links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='list']/a")))]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(locations, prices, links)), columns=['Location', 'Price', 'Link'])
  print(df)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
      Location       Price                                               Link
  0     LISBON    €350,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/lisbon-...
  1   COMPORTA  €280,000 +  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/alentej...
  2     LISBON  €350,000 +  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/service...
  3   COMPORTA  €340,000 +  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/unique-...
  4     LISBON  €512,737 +  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/private...
  5   ALENTEJO    €400,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/stylish...
  6    ALGARVE    €280,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/marina-...
  7      PORTO    €350,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/porto-i...
  8      PORTO    €350,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/porto-g...
  9      EVORA    €280,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/evora-a...
  10   ALGARVE  €280,000 +  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/algarve...
  11     EVORA    €280,000  https://www.goldenvisas.com/investment/boutiqu...
  ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! Is there a way I can check the contents of the href 'misc-location' and gathering all the information, 'features', inside of the href?

Comment: Of coarse you can.